# Merge Google Accounts

Tags: google-workspace, google-account, google-analytics, google-adwords

I have a client that has 3 different business emails. He's using one for Google Analytics/Search Console which is currently linked to his website. He's using the other for his AdWords/Google Business Listing. I know that merging Google accounts isn't possible per their article here: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/63304?hl=en

I've also seen Google's data transfer tool, but did not see an option for AdWords or Analytics.

I tried to change his email address on his AdWords account to match the one on his Analytics account, but received an error saying "Sorry, a Gmail address is not allowed to be the primary address of this account".

1. Why won't Google allow a Gmail address for the primary address on an AdWords account?
2. Is there a way to link these two accounts and have one login?

Any suggestions are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

There are three different ways to change AdWords sign in information.

1. Change the email address on your account
2. Add alternate email addresses to your account
3. Allow another email address to access your AdWords account

The option to change the email address is not available to Google accounts, only non Google accounts. The alternate email address option is only available if the address you are trying to add is not the primary email address on another account.

Try giving access to the AdWords account instead of changing the email associated with it. Grant administrative access for the other account to have access the entire AdWords account.

[Source: Change your AdWords sign-in information](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1704356?hl=en)